# pouchdb + vuex update live with changes

Tags: vue.js, couchdb, vuex, pouchdb

I have an app that takes updates into VUEX store and syncs those change from pouchdb to couchdb. Which is great but now I need to have two clients connected and see the change in near realtime.

So I have the https://pouchdb.com/guides/changes.html API which I can use to listen for changes to the DB and when that happens call a action which mutates the vuex state on Client 2. Code below.

However the bit I cannot seem to work out is this code is not just listening all the time ? So where should I put this in Vue to ensure that it hears any changes. I can call it when I make a state change and I see that it hears the change but ofcourse I want to trigger a state change on client 2, without them having to make change. Do I need a timer ? The pouch docs seem to suggest this changes api should be able to update UI based on a change to the data, which I can probably call with a button press to check for changes ...but I want to listen in near realtime ?

```
pouchdb
        .changes({
          since: 'now',
          include_docs: true
        })
        .on('change', function(change) {
          // received a change
          store.commit('CHANGE_STATE', change.doc.flavour)
        })
        .on('error', function(err) {
          // handle errors
          console.log(err)
        })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I ended up doing !

```
actions: {
    SYNC_DB() {
      // do one way, one-off sync from the server until completion
      pouchdb.replicate.from(remote).on('complete', function(info) {
        // then two-way, continuous, retriable sync
        pouchdb
          .sync(remote, { live: true, retry: true })
          .on('change', function(info) {
             store.commit('CHANGE_STATE', info.change.docs[0].flavour)
          })
          .on('paused', function(err) {
            // replication paused (e.g. replication up to date, user went offline)
          })
          .on('active', function() {
            // replicate resumed (e.g. new changes replicating, user went back online)
          })
          .on('denied', function(err) {
            // a document failed to replicate (e.g. due to permissions)
          })
          .on('complete', function(info) {
            // handle complete
          })
          .on('error', function(err) {
            // handle error
          })
      })
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

Your explanation is a bit fuzzy in that you talk about `client 2` without ever mentioning `client 1`.  I assume `client 2` is a passive listener and `client 1` is where data is changed.  If I remember correctly from when I was building my Vue / PouchDB project last year I looked into how to coordinate the Store and the Database, and then thought, *"Why bother? They're just two kinds of local storage"*.  As long as changes in `client 1` replicate to your Couch server and `client 2` detects those server side changes and writes them into reactive variables, they'll propagate to the UI.

I used `replicate.to()` for storing client-side changes and `replicate.from()` to detect server-side changes. The `replicate()` functions have their own timer, constantly monitoring the changes queue, so you don't need to roll your own.

Comment: yes sorry client 1 would be issuing a change and client 2 would need to see the change when it occurs without interacting. At the moment I am using db.sync and db.get/ db.put to update the pouch and then couch, I am not using any replicate functions... could you explain a little more on how you used replicate.from() to detect server changes and put them into vue

Comment: I use - pouchdb.sync(remote, { live: true, retry: true }) - but this is just called on loading ?

Comment: https://gitlab.adamprocter.co.uk/adamprocter/simplevuestore/blob/changes/src/store.js